# Adding error bars using equation in Gnuplot

Tags: plot, error-handling, gnuplot, gnu, static-analysis

I have a transducer data where I know I have a sudden accuracy:
[image: This is the error within the different transducers in the y-axes]

My question is: **How to add y-errorbars into my existing code?**

```
set xlabel "Time [min]" 
set ylabel "Temperature [Celsius]"
plot '150830AW.dat'  every ::1188::1231 using 4:52 w l lc rgb 'green' title "Run 1", \
    '150830AW.dat'  every ::1251::1284 using 4:52 w l lc rgb 'blue' title "Run 2", \
                        90 title "Standard" with lines linestyle 2
```

and

```
set xlabel "Time [min]"
set ylabel "Pressure [MPa]"
plot '2015 08 30 0000 Pelletizer Feed (Wide).dat'  every ::2372::2459 using 4:($8*0.006894759086775369) w l lc rgb 'green' title "Run 1", \
    '2015 08 30 0000 Pelletizer Feed (Wide).dat'  every ::2498::2565 using 4:($8*0.006894759086775369) w l lc rgb 'blue' title "Run 2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these demos: [errorbars](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.0/mgr.html). Basically you need a third column with the error.

Since you have 0.5% accuracy on Pressure, you'll have to multiply the pressure column by 0.005 so that your `using 4:52` will become `using 4:52:($52*0.005)`.

To activate the errorbar you need to replace the `w l` (i.e. with lines) with `with errorbars`.

If you want both the line **and** errorbars you have to keep your line and add this new line, e.g:

```
plot '150830AW.dat'  every ::1188::1231 using 4:52 w l lc rgb 'green' title "Run 1", \
     ''  every ::1188::1231 using 4:52:($52*0.005) w errorbar lc rgb 'green' notitle, \
     '150830AW.dat'  every ::1251::1284 using 4:52 w l lc rgb 'blue' title "Run 2", \
     ''  every ::1251::1284 using 4:52:($52*0.005) w errorbar lc rgb 'blue' notitle, \
     90 title "Standard" with lines linestyle 2
```

If you want something IMHO nicer, have a look at [fill between curves](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.0/fillbetween.html)